# Non-linear second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I have to solve $$ y''(x)+(y'(x))^2=y'(x). $$

Using $ y'(x)=z $, I can write $$\int \frac{1}{z-z^2}dz=\int dx $$

So: 
$$\frac{1}{z(1-z)}=\frac{A}{z}+\frac{B}{1-z}$$
leads to

$$ \int \frac{1}{z(1-z)}dz=\int \frac{1}{z}dz+\int \frac{1}{1-z}dz= \ln(z)-\ln(1-z)$$
$$\Rightarrow \ln\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)=x+c $$
$$\Rightarrow z=\frac{e^{x+c}}{1+e^{x+c}}=y'$$
$$\Rightarrow y=\int \frac{e^{x+c}}{1+e^{x+c}}dx $$

Now, calling $e^{x+c}=t$:

$$y=\int\frac{t}{1+t}\cdot\frac{dt}{t}=\ln(1+t)\Rightarrow \ln(1+e^{x+c})$$

I checked the calculations and i thought was right but WolframAlpha says that the result is $\ln(c_1+e^x)+c_2$. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong. The answer you got is $\ln(1+e^{x+c_1})+c_2$. It is equal to:

\begin{align}
\ln(1+e^{x+c_1})+c_2 &= \ln(e^{c_1}(e^x+\frac{1}{e^{c_1}}))+c_2 \\
&= \ln(e^{c_1})+\ln(e^x+\frac{1}{e^{c_1}})+c_2 \\
&= \ln(\frac{1}{e^{c_1}}+e^x)+(c_1+c_2). 
\end{align}

Now let $d_1=\frac{1}{e^{c_1}}$, $d_2=c_1+c_2$ and you will get the answer from wolfram.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot the initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$: how can i use them to find the solution?

Comment: Well, you have the general solution, but now you also want to find the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ for the solution function to be unique. From the function that you found you can also find its derivative. Then put the point $(0,0)$ in $y$ and the point $(0,1)$ in $y'$ and you will get a system of two equations from which you can find the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I thought so. Actually i asked you because, obtaining from the system that $e^{c_1}=0$, i should conclude that there are no solutions?

Comment: No, you probably made a mistake. You have $y=ln(c_1+e^x)+c_2$ and $y'=\frac{e^x}{c_1+e^x}$. So from $y'(0)=1$ you get that $\frac{1}{c_1+1}=1$ and hence $c_1=0$. Putting that into $y$ gives that $y=ln(e^x)+c_2=x+c_2$, and the equation $y(0)=0$ gives $c_2=0$. So the solution function is $y=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from missing the absolute sign for `log`. You have the following issues
$$
y = \int \frac{1}{1+t}dt \to \ln(1+t) + C_2
$$
then couple this with the following.
$$
\log(1 + \mathrm{e}^{x+c}) = \log(1 + A\mathrm{e}^{x}) = \log A\left(\frac{1}{A} + \mathrm{e}^{x}\right)  = \log A + \log \left(\frac{1}{A} + \mathrm{e}^{x}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Calling $z = y'$ we have

$$
z' + z^2-z = 0
$$

Making now $u = \frac 1z\Rightarrow u'+u-1=0\Rightarrow u = 1+C_0 e^{-x}$ then

$$
z = \frac{1}{u} = \frac{e^x}{e^e+C_0}\Rightarrow y = \int z dx = \ln(e^x+C_0) + C_1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$ y=\int \frac{e^{x+c}}{1+e^{x+c}}dx$$

$$t=e^{x+c} \implies dt =e^{x+c}dx$$

$$ y=\int \frac{e^{x+c}}{1+e^{x+c}}dx =\int \frac{dt}{1+t} $$

$$ = \ln(1+t)+c_2 = \ln(1+e^{x+c} ) +c_2$$

Their answer $$ ln(c_1+e^x)+c_2 = \ln c_1(1+e^x/{c_1})+c_2=\ln c_1 + ln (1+c_1^{-1} e^x)+c_2$$ is equivalent to your solution via renaming the constants.